# How to open settings app programmatically?

Tags: swift, application-settings, ios8.3

I'm using swift with ios 8.3. I want to open settings app from my application. I know that using the code

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```

will open my app settings. But I don't want to open my app settings. I just want to open the settings app and stay in the main page. If possible, navigate to "Cellular". Is there any way to acheive this?

Comment: hello,
have you found any solution for open setting main page ?

Comment: No. I think there's no solution for my question

Answer (score 42):

Try this.

```
if let appSettings = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(appSettings, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Xcode 11.5 - iOS > 10

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer; others use iOS internals that can result in App Store rejections.

Comment: this is opening my app settings on iOS 12

Comment: There is no way currently to open even the main Settings screen (using public API), only settings of your app in Settings.

Comment: perfect. This is the answer.

Answer (score 18):

**Update on 11-Oct-2016:**

It won't work in iOS10 anymore. So far I haven't found any workaround. If you guys have any solution please let me know. thanks.

======================================

if the iOS version <= iOS9, you need set URL types:
[image]

You can do in this way:

```
    let url:NSURL! = NSURL(string : "prefs:root=")
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

I have a demo on github: http://github.com/zhihuitang/SettingDemo.git

And you can find all available URLs as follows:
http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Preferences.app
Preferences app registers a private URL scheme, prefs:, the list below details opening specific views [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4gap.jpg)[2]

```
prefs:root=General&path=About
prefs:root=General&path=ACCESSIBILITY
prefs:root=AIRPLANE_MODE
prefs:root=General&path=AUTOLOCK
prefs:root=General&path=USAGE/CELLULAR_USAGE
prefs:root=General&path=Bluetooth
prefs:root=General&path=DATE_AND_TIME
prefs:root=FACETIME
prefs:root=General
prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard
prefs:root=CASTLE
prefs:root=CASTLE&path=STORAGE_AND_BACKUP
prefs:root=General&path=INTERNATIONAL
prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES
prefs:root=ACCOUNT_SETTINGS
prefs:root=MUSIC
prefs:root=MUSIC&path=EQ
prefs:root=MUSIC&path=VolumeLimit
prefs:root=General&path=Network
prefs:root=NIKE_PLUS_IPOD
prefs:root=NOTES
prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID
prefs:root=Phone
prefs:root=Photos
prefs:root=General&path=ManagedConfigurationList
prefs:root=General&path=Reset
prefs:root=Sounds&path=Ringtone
prefs:root=Safari
prefs:root=General&path=Assistant
prefs:root=Sounds
prefs:root=General&path=SOFTWARE_UPDATE_LINK
prefs:root=STORE
prefs:root=TWITTER
prefs:root=General&path=USAGE
prefs:root=VIDEO
prefs:root=General&path=Network/VPN
prefs:root=Wallpaper
prefs:root=WIFI
prefs:root=INTERNET_TETHERING
```

hope this helpful to you.

Comment: That code is what I am using now. Sachin Rocken, could you paste your code here? Let's see what is the problem.

Comment: let url:NSURL! = NSURL(string : "prefs:root=General")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)

That doesn't work.

Comment: @User9527 , I tried your code. In viewdidload I used   let url:NSURL! = NSURL(string : "prefs:root=")
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)     and it's not working. I don't know how it's working for you. Could you please give a sample project using any sharing services available.

Comment: @Sachin Rocken, I made a demo in github, please check if it works with you:https://github.com/zhihuitang/SettingDemo.git

Comment: It is actually working if you consider this tip here to "configure the URL Schemes in your project": https://gist.github.com/phynet/471089a51b8f940f0fb4

Comment: Have anybody got the solution for iOS 10?

Comment: Under iOS 10 "prefs:###" has been changed to "App-Prefs:###". The rest of the string should be the same.

Comment: Please use my code which i have given above. Its successfully working mine

Comment: This API is private and Apple will most likely reject your app if you will want to send it to the store.

Answer (score 10):

YES, They made changes in iOS 10, Please change "prefs:" to "App-Prefs:"

```swift
guard let profileUrl = URL(string:"App-Prefs:root=General&path=ManagedConfigurationList") else {
    return
}

if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(profileUrl) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(profileUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
        print(" Profile Settings opened: \(success)")
    })
}
```

Comment: This is a hack and will result in rejection from App Store.

Comment: hoo really, Thanks for your information Sibir, Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: @BoosaRamesh Doesn't look like it. :(

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 14:
you can do:

```
// System settings:
let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!
UIApplication.shared.open(url)

// Notifications settings:
URL(string: UIApplication.openNotificationSettingsURLString)!
UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```